# Assign Opposite Tag

Tags: dplyr

I have data as a sample given below :

```
customerNames.1=c('A','B','A','C','E','F')
customerNames.2=c('B','A','C','A','F','E')
Relation=c('Father','NA','Spouse','NA','Mother','NA')
Datasample=data.table(customerNames.1,customerNames.2,Relation)

# data looks like 

   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
1:               A               B   Father
2:               B               A       NA
3:               A               C   Spouse
4:               C               A       NA
5:               E               F   Mother
6:               F               E       NA
```

Each row shows relation of customer.1 to customer.2 , here while A to B relation  is there in the main source , i also want to record B to A with their relation ( which can be derived from the first relation  e.g. Father - child , Spouse - Spouse , Mother - Child )

How do i get something like below :

```
   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
1:               A               B   Father
2:               B               A    Child
3:               A               C   Spouse
4:               C               A   Spouse
5:               E               F   Mother
6:               F               E    Child
```

Comment: May I ask why you reverted the tag edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `tidyverse`, you can do something like that to compute your missing relation. It may not be the easiest but it works as you want I think.

Get your source table, compute your relation based on this info and join to your missing relations to complete your table.

```r
customerNames.1=c('A','B','A','C','E','F')
customerNames.2=c('B','A','C','A','F','E')
Relation=c('Father',NA_character_,'Spouse',NA_character_,'Mother',NA_character_)
library(dplyr)
Datasample=data_frame(customerNames.1,customerNames.2,Relation)
Datasample
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
#>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#> 1               A               B   Father
#> 2               B               A     <NA>
#> 3               A               C   Spouse
#> 4               C               A     <NA>
#> 5               E               F   Mother
#> 6               F               E     <NA>

sourceTab <- tidyr::drop_na(Datasample) 
sourceTab
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
#>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#> 1               A               B   Father
#> 2               A               C   Spouse
#> 3               E               F   Mother
computeTab <- sourceTab %>%
  select(customerNames.1 = customerNames.2, customerNames.2 = customerNames.1, Relation) %>%
  mutate(Relation = 
           case_when(
             Relation %in% c("Father", "Mother") ~ "Child",
             Relation == "Spouse" ~ "Spouse",
             TRUE ~ NA_character_
           ))
computeTab  
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
#>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#> 1               B               A    Child
#> 2               C               A   Spouse
#> 3               F               E    Child
completedTab <- Datasample %>% 
  left_join(computeTab, by = c("customerNames.1", "customerNames.2")) %>%
  mutate(Relation = case_when(
    !is.na(Relation.x) ~ Relation.x,
    is.na(Relation.x) & !is.na(Relation.y) ~ Relation.y,
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  select(starts_with("customer"), Relation)
completedTab  
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
#>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#> 1               A               B   Father
#> 2               B               A    Child
#> 3               A               C   Spouse
#> 4               C               A   Spouse
#> 5               E               F   Mother
#> 6               F               E    Child
bind_rows(sourceTab, completedTab)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   customerNames.1 customerNames.2 Relation
#>             <chr>           <chr>    <chr>
#> 1               A               B   Father
#> 2               A               C   Spouse
#> 3               E               F   Mother
#> 4               A               B   Father
#> 5               B               A    Child
#> 6               A               C   Spouse
#> 7               C               A   Spouse
#> 8               E               F   Mother
#> 9               F               E    Child
```